# How do I simplify these nested for loops?

Tags: python-3.x

I was given this riddle :

[image]

My first idea was to solve it using python. (Later I realized algebra would have been much easier).

Here was my initial code:

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0

for a in range(100):
    for b in range(100):
        for c in range(100):
            for d in range(100):

                if float(a + b)/4 == 8.0:
                    if float(a + c)/4 == 13.0:
                        if float(c - d)/4 == 6.0:
                            if float(b + d)/4 == 8.0:
                                print(float(a + b)/4, end=" ")
                                print(float(a + c)/4, end=" ")
                                print(float(c + -d)/4, end=" ")
                                print(float(b + d)/4, end=" and values are:")
                                print(a/4, end=" ")
                                print(b/4, end=" ")
                                print(c/4, end=" ")
                                print(d/4)
```

It worked, but obviously this is not very readable.
Looking on stack overflow leads to the solution being **recursive functions**, however I do not know how exactly to apply this because there are four different mathematical calculations.

For example this is what I tried at first:

```
val = [0, 0, 0, 0]

def recursive_solution(section):
    for val[section] in range(100):
        for val[section+1] in range(100):
            if section == 0:
                if float(val[section])/4 + float(val[section + 1])/4 == 8:
                    recursive_solution(1)


recursive_solution(0)
```

But this obviously does not work, as the second index is added to the fourth index, and one of the operations is a subtraction, and you can't add the fourth index to the fifth one because the fifth one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do from your code: use a cartesian [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) and `and` statements:

```
from collections import product
for a, b, c, d in product(*([range(100)] * 4))
    if (
        float(a + b) / 4 == 8.0
        and float(a + c) / 4 == 13.0
        and float(c - d) / 4 == 6.0
        and float(b + d) / 4 == 8.0
    ):
        print(float(a + b) / 4, end=" ")
        print(float(a + c) / 4, end=" ")
        print(float(c + -d) / 4, end=" ")
        print(float(b + d) / 4, end=" and values are:")
        print(a / 4, end=" ")
        print(b / 4, end=" ")
        print(c / 4, end=" ")
        print(d / 4)
```